# nginx proxy_pass fails to serve static files

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have been trying to achieve the following, thought failing miserably for days now.

I am trying to reverse proxy 2 services based on url paths as per follow:

```
http://host/api/ => http://backend/
http://host/backoffice/ => http://backoffice/
```

(and all trailing path after should be carried on services 1 and 2, ie 
`http://host/service1/foo/bar => http://server1/foo/bar`)

The redirection works well when I am accessing non static files (service 1 is a rest API that responds) but I have the following when it comes to accessing static ressources (service 2 is a react application served by an nginx server). Reverse proxy is indicating 404 on css and js files.

The configuration for the proxy is the following:

```
http {

include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  10;

client_header_timeout 10;
client_body_timeout 10;

send_timeout 10;

tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;

proxy_redirect     off;
proxy_set_header   Host $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443;
    server_name  reverse-proxy;

    location /backoffice/ {
       proxy_pass http://backoffice:80/;
       rewrite /backoffice/(.*) /$1  break;
    }
    location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend:8000/;
    rewrite /backend/(.*) /$1  break;
    }
  } 
}
```

Looking at the logs of the reverse proxy, I read the following:

```
172.31.39.227 - - [03/Sep/2019:08:37:44 +0000] "GET 
/static/js/2.741f53a0.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 572 "http://host/backoffice/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; 
Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
2019/09/03 08:37:44 [error] 7#7: *669 open() 
"/etc/nginx/html/static/js/2.741f53a0.chunk.js" failed (2: No such 
file or directory), client: <host-ip>, server: reverse-proxy, 
request: "GET /static/js/2.741f53a0.chunk.js HTTP/1.1", host: 
"host", referrer: 
"http://host/backoffice/"
2019/09/03 08:37:44 [error] 7#7: *671 open() 
"/etc/nginx/html/static/js/main.cf227c52.chunk.js" failed (2: No such 
file or directory), client: <host-ip>, server: reverse-proxy, 
request: "GET /static/js/main.cf227c52.chunk.js HTTP/1.1", host: 
"host", referrer: 
"http://host/backoffice/"
<server ip> - - [03/Sep/2019:08:37:44 +0000] "GET 
/static/js/main.cf227c52.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 572 "http://host/backoffice/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; 
Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
```

(I changed hostnames and IP in that log)

I initially did the redirection based on port listeners and it worked like a charm but for DNS purposes I cannot rely on that solution.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: i aint understand the last sentence, what do you expect about what should be done?

Comment: I'm expecting getting static files served through the reverse proxy based on the above configuration, while I am actually getting those errors

Comment: dont use nginx conf for servers use site-avaible and link tzem to site-enabled

Comment: You mean migrating to apache ?

Comment: no, this is the same on nginx